# What's the Objective-C equivalent of JS's `map()` function?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, porting

What's the Objective-C equivalent of JS's `map()` function? Would I just use NSFastEnumeration and apply the function myself?

Comment: It's built in with Swift, only 3 and a half years after you asked this question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `NSArray`'s [`enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:) if you're on OS X 10.6 or iOS 4.:

```
NSMutableArray *mapped = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[array count]];
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    id mapObj = DoSomethingToObject(obj);
    [mapped addObject:mapObj];
}];
```

<sup>(Shameless but relevant plug: I have a [library](https://github.com/mdippery/collections) for OS X and iOS that adds map and other similar functionality to `NSArray` and `NSSet`.)</sup>

Comment: @Moshe: Then you'll just have to do it with a for loop.

Comment: +1 for the link to your collections library. Don't be _ashamed_ of sharing your good work, for crying out loud! It looks like a great resource.

Comment: A small example of usage wouldn't hurt though ...

Answer (score 14):

It depends.  If you have, say, an array of objects, and these objects have a `URL` property (for example), then you can do:

```
NSArray * urls = [myArray valueForKey:@"URL"];
```

Likewise, if you can trigger the behavior of the objects in question via a single message that takes 0 or 1 parameters, you can do:

```
[myArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(doFoo)];
//or:
[myArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(doFooWithBar:) withObject:aBar];
```

For anything beyond that, you'll have to iterate over the objects yourself.  You can use a `for()` loop, a `for(in)` loop, or something like `-enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`, etc.

Comment: This works great! `valueForKey:` works nice with an array of NSDictionary too.

Answer (score 9):

You do it yourself. There is no single method equivalent to what you want.

**Edit**: For those downvoting, this was the correct answer at the time (three years ago) and still is for Objective-C, but Swift does have a `map()` function.

Comment: Though technically correct, your answer is not very helpful. You could have included some code, like Nicolas Manzini did, in order to earn the points.

Answer (score 4):

Check [BlocksKit](https://github.com/zwaldowski/BlocksKit), it provides map, reduce and filer for NSArray.

> - (NSArray *)map:(BKTransformBlock)block;
> - (id)reduce:(id)initial withBlock:(BKAccumulationBlock)block;
> - (NSArray *)select:(BKValidationBlock)block;

Answer (score 2):

Category function for **NSArray** an alternative

```
- (NSArray *)map:(id(^)(id, BOOL *))block {
    NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        id newObject = block(obj,stop);
        if (newObject == nil) {
            newObject = [NSNull null];
        }
        [array addObject:newObject];
    }];
    return array.copy;
}
```

Category function for **NSMutableArray** an alternative

```
- (NSMutableArray *)map:(id(^)(id))block {
    NSEnumerator * enumerator = ((NSArray *)self.copy).objectEnumerator;
    id obj; NSUInteger idx = 0;
    while ((obj = enumerator.nextObject)) {
        self[idx] = block(obj) ?: [NSNull null];
        idx++;
    }
    return self;
}
```